# Going from java.util.time to jodatime

Tags: java, string, parsing, datetime, jodatime

```
String t = s.replaceAll(".*;\\s+", ""); //Output: Tue Mar 5 08:30:20 2013 +0000
DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy Z",Locale.ENGLISH);
Date time = parser.parse(t);
```

This is what I used when I was using java.util.Date, but I sometimes have problems when I compare 2 Date objects, I tried using Calendar  but to no avail, and then I stumbled upon JodaTime. So after that I thought I'd try using their DateTIme format and see how that would work but I get:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Tue Mar 5 08:30:20 2013 +0000"

when I try to convert the string to a DateTime format using this code:

```
String t = s.replaceAll(".*;\\s+", ""); //Output: Tue Mar 5 08:30:20 2013 +0000
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy Z");
DateTime time = DateTime.parse(t, parser);
```

What am I doing wrong? As far as I can see the pattern I use is the same, I tried replacing "HH" with "kk", but it gave the same result.

Comment: I guess you meant `parser.parseDateTime(t)` in the last line of code. It works perfectly for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a Locale solved it:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy Z").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```